# Flexbox - how to align items vertically with flex-col?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

```
const Product = ({product}) => {
    return (
        <div className="rounded shadow flex-col justify-center overflow-hidden">
            <img className="" src={product.image} />
            <span className="block h-16">{product.name}</span>
            <span className="block">{product.price}</span>
            <button className="px-4 py-2 my-2 bg-green-200 rounded block">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is a card component in React using Tailwind CSS.
I cannot get the items to be centered in the card.

I used flex-col so the direction is now vertical and tried justify-center as well as items-center with tailwind but it doesn't seem to be moving anything.

If you use flex-col doesn't the axis get swapped so you need to use align-items: center to make it vertically centered?

Answer (score 2):

The `justify-content` CSS property aligns on the current `flex-direction` axis, while the `align-items` CSS property aligns on the axis perpendicular to the current `flex-direction`.

Therefore, if the container has `flex-direction` set to `column` (`.flex-col`), you need to use `.items-center` (in CSS: `align-items: center`) to center its children horizontally.

However, if the centered child is block level, its text might still be left-aligned even though the element, (being a 100% width box) ***is centered*** in the column, in which case you'll need to use `text-align: center` (`.text-center`) on the child to horizontally align its contents.

For an in-depth article on flexbox, I recommend [A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification this makes sense.